# Uploading picture in mysite: An unrecoverable error has occurred. Please contact your system administrator

Tags: 2007, image-upload

I am using sharepoint 2007. I have 1 webapplication and this is my intranet. I have also configured MySite inside this webapplication. When I go to mysite -> my profile -> details, I can upload my picture. Everything is working fine.

When another user is doing this he gots the following error:

> An unrecoverable error has occurred. Please contact your system
>   administrator

[image]
The onlu differance between him and me, is I am working with the SPinstall account and he is working with a normal end user account.

Anybody know what the issue is?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the configuration of your Web-Applications and the App-Pools (that the same service account used for My Site and Intranet web app-pools). It's seems both worked with different Service Accounts for the Application Pool of the Webapplication.

Answer (score 0):

I give this user full control permissions to he's own mysite. Now he is possible to upload images. Strange behavior because he is site collection administrator in Central Admin on the site collection of he's mysite.